Collapse all rows in DataFrame into one row with new ordered columns
I have a huge DataFrame (16 million rows, 24 columns) and I need to iterate each row, transpose it (so that it has 24 rows), merge each new row with another df, and then I need to collapse these 24 rows back into a single row with the original row index.
These rows then need to be added back into a a 16m row dataframe to run a Kmeans clustering on. I realize that it's very time consuming, and that's OK, I'm only worried about Memory errors.
I have a df with factorized values shaped like this:
        0   1   2   3
index                                                                                   
0       1   2   3   4    
1       1   2   3   5
...

And a df2 with data for each factorized value:
factor  0   1   2   3   4    
1       0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 NaN
2       5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 NaN
3       10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0
4       15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0
5       20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0
...

I used groupby index to get a df for each row:
spatial_row = df.groupby('index')

And then I iterate over each group to combine the value (renamed 'factor' column) with the data for each value (df2)
for a in spatial_row:
    df = a[1].T.rename(columns=({df.columns[0]: 'factor'}))
    df_index = a[0]
    df.merge(df2, on='factor')
    df.drop('factor', axis=1, inplace=True)
    

And an example of the data structure I'm getting for index==1 (with 4 rows instead of 24 and 4 columns instead of 444):
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 NaN
1   5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 NaN
2   10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0
3   20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0

Now I need these 4 rows to collapse into a single row with (row number * column number) columns, say the df_index = 1:
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
1     0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 NaN 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 NaN 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0

(with my data Each row will have 10656 (444 x 24) columns). Then it's saved as a dict/series/list with its index (df_index) to be joined with all other iterations into a new DataFrame (with 16m rows again). I can't find a more memory efficient way of doing this without crashing, vectorizing doesn't work (too heavy) and I don't mind waiting a few hours for it to complete.

Basically you want to get an 1D array of your dataframe row wise right ?

read notice : [mre]

You could vectorize this, but with 16M rows as input it's not a good size for pandas. The intermediate will be huge. Please clarify the question by demonstrating the complete logic with a [mre] (i.e. all inputs, and the code to aggregate the merged intermediate back to a single row)

Thank you for your answers, I updated the question with a reproducible example, I hope that's a lot more clear now.

@LevZhitnik please provide code to set up a MRE for spatial_row and df2 (using the DataFrame constructor). see here

@mozway I added an example of the original df that turns into spatial_row and df2. I hope it makes better sense now
